# Jquery get the real value of the element used to initialize a pluginplugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to use [Stefan Gabos's](https://gist.github.com/skydark/2555172) revisited boilerplate template for my own plugin.

Everything works well, but I want to know how I can get the "real" element I used to initialize the plugin.

Plugin

```
 ;(function ($, window, document, undefined) {

    'use strict';

    $.pluginName = function(element, options) {

        var defaults = {
            foo: 'bar'
        }

        var plugin = this;
        var elem = element;

        plugin.settings = {};

        plugin.init = function() {
            plugin.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

            console.log(elem);

        }
        plugin.init();
    }

    $.fn.pluginName = function(options) {
        return this.each(function() {
            if (undefined == $(this).data('pluginName')) {
                var plugin = new $.pluginName(this, options);
                $(this).data('pluginName', plugin);
            }
        });
    }

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

HTML

```
<select class=".foo" id="foo" name="foo" data-name="foo">
```

JS

```
$('#foo').pluginName(); //<select class=".foo" id="foo" name="foo" data-name="foo">

$('[name="foo"]').pluginName(); //<select class=".foo" id="foo" name="foo" data-name="foo">

$('.foo').pluginName(); //<select class=".foo" id="foo" name="foo" data-name="foo">
```

I would like to get

```
$('#foo').pluginName(); //#foo

$('[name="foo"]').pluginName(); //[name="foo"]

$('.foo').pluginName(); //.foo
```

How I could only get this parameter and not all the DOM element ?
Thanks

Comment: Why do you need this? You can just save the jQuery object in a variable and use that to reference the element when needed

Comment: Yes, I know this, but I also have to add the element to an array for various reasons

Comment: That doesn't affect the logic - you can add the jQuery object to an array too

Comment: In the array I have the "name" of other element, not the element object. [''#bar', '#red', '.other']

Comment: Fair enough - although that would appear to be a bad way of doing things if you already have a reference to the elements needed.

Comment: The element must be chained to others element that user must insert in the options. The user insert name/id of the element not the element's object